# Python - Searching through dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary which stores locations of mobs/monsters:

```
mobs = {}
mobs[0] = {'x': 45, 'y': 65, 'HP': 12, 'target':0 }
mobs[1] = {'x': 57, 'y': 15, 'HP': 37, 'target':0 }
mobs[2] = {'x': 33, 'y': 87, 'HP': 24, 'target':0 }
```

I also have a similar dict for `players = {}`

When a player moves, I want to search through the mobs dict and find all mobs which are in range- that is both X and Y distance is under 5.

I'm only a few days into learning Python, and from what I know so far I can do this by looping through the dict each time the player moves:

```
for a in mobs:
    mobX = mobs[a]['x']
    mobY = mobs[a]['y']
    # compare to playerX,playerY etc
```

But I'm sure there's a better/quicker way? Just concerned that if there was hundreds of entries in the mobs dict would this loop get slow? Would SQLite or a database be better?

Comment: You underestimate the speed of computers. Speed will only become an issue if there are millions of entries. This is fine.

Comment: there is no need to worry, python use hash table underlying the dict, which means it is very fast, faster than look up value in list.